# Summing RasterStacks when Rasterstacks are in a list of unknown length

Tags: r, r-raster, rgdal

I have a list of Rasterstacks each with 2 layers. I want to add all the Rasterstacks in a list together into a single Rasterstack with 2 layers. Assuming I have a list of 2 Rasterstacks, each with 2 layers, I would use the following command

```
raster_stack_sum = raster_list[[1]] + raster_list[[2]]
```

which would return a single Rasterstack with 2 layers. My question is how would I do this when the length of the list (ie the number of RasterStacks) is unknown. Is there an equivalent shorter way to run the below line of code when the length of the list (in this case 5) is unknown?

```
raster_stack_sum = raster_list[[1]] + raster_list[[2]] + 
raster_list[[3]]+ raster_list[[4]] + raster_list[[5]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `stack` to create a new `RasterStack` from a list of `Raster*` objects.

Example data:

```
library(raster)
s <- stack(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster")) 
x <- list(s, s, s)
```

Solution:

```
sum(stack(x))
```

What makes you say that "storing a list of Rasterstacks is deprecated"?

*edit*

To sum a list of RasterStack objects layer by layer, I would use a loop

```
y <- x[[1]]
for (i in 2:length(x)) { y = y + x[[i]] }
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response, this is a good answer, except it doesn't work when the stacks are multilayered and I want a single summed Rasterstack with the same number of layers of each of the individual Rasterstacks. I've updated the question to reflect my specific question